# how can I stop python script without killing it?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I want to know if there is a way to stop the python script when it is running, without killing it.

For example, I know `ctrl + z or c` will kill the current processes.. but I don't want to kill the program..

my python program takes one files at a time and execute some jobs.. 
each file takes about 10~20 minutes depends on the size of the file.. and there are many files in a directory..

but sometimes I have to let it finish the file that it is currently working on stop the program right after that current file instead of killing it in the middle of the work.

How can I do this in python? I want to write this python coding if I can..

I've tried

```
if os.path.exists(filename)
    sys exit(0)
```

but this one, I have to create a file while it is running so that when it reaches that file, it stops... but instead of doing this.. I want to see if there are better way to stop it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but sometimes I have to let it finish the file that it is currently working on stop the program right after that current file instead of killing it in the middle of the work.

This is more specific than Ctrl+Z; you're asking to stop the program, but not right away.  You can use signals for this.  Set a signal handler with `signal`, and invoke it with `kill -SIGWHATEVER` at the command line.  The signal handler, generally speaking, should just set a flag that you check periodically; it should not actually "do anything" by itself, since you don't know what state your program is in when it's called.

A signal handler is a function that gets called when your program receives a signal.  They are set using [`signal.signal()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal).  Signals are sent with the `kill` program, or the `kill()` system call.  Your handler would look like this:

```
stop = False
def handler(number, frame):
    global stop
    stop = True
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
for file in files:  # or whatever your main loop looks like
    # Process one file
    if stop:
        break
```

Comment: @Kevin oh so you mean write something like `while not stop` in all the for or while loops that I am using? in you new coding you didn't use while or for loop but used if loop to check if it should break out or not..  so in my program I should do something similar in all for loop and/or while loops.. right?

Comment: @PETER: Put the `if` somewhere that will be executed between files.  If you need to break out of multiple loops, you can call `sys.exit()` instead.  That's probably a good idea anyway, because it lets you include an error message explaining that you had to stop early.

Comment: @Kevin so I tried so many times.. trying to kill pid.. but it is not working.. it doesnt even give me an error.. while I am running my python.. i do `ps ax | grep pythonname` and `kill -SIGUSR1 Pidofpython` but it is not killing it.. i tried testing by printing stop before it goes into the `if stop:` but its always `False`...

Comment: @PETER: Did you look at my example program I linked to earlier? It illustrates how to write code that responds to a signal. Some parts of that program might be a bit too advanced for your current level of Pyt5hon understanding, but hopefully it's not totally unreadable for you.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Z` will only *suspend* the process, not kill it. You can later type `fg` to resume it ("fg" stands for "foreground". also, you can run "bg" for "background"). From what you describe, this sounds like a good solution to achieve what you want.

This, of course, applies to any process, not only python.

Comment: You can also use bg to resume it in background mode

Comment: Ctrl+z will suspend it right away without letting my program to finish my current file.. so this doesn't work for me.. I need my python to finish the current file before suspending it or stopping it. @shx2

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch the Interrupt Exception (Ctrl + C) and then process the unfinished file and come out of it.

```
`def main():
    try:
        for file in file_list:
            process(file)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        process(file)
        raise Exception`
```